# To what level does MongoDB lock on writes? (or: what does it mean by "per connection"

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking

In the mongodb documentation, it says:

> Beginning with version 2.2, MongoDB implements locks on a per-database basis for most read and write operations. Some global operations, typically short lived operations involving multiple databases, still require a global “instance” wide lock. Before 2.2, there is only one “global” lock per mongod instance.

Does this mean that in the situation that I Have, say, 3 connections to mongodb://localhost/test from different apps running on the network - only one could be writing at a time? Or is it just per connection?

IOW: Is it per connection, or is the whole /test database locked while it writes?

Comment: Starting in MongoDB 3.0, the WiredTiger storage engine is available in the 64-bit builds.
WiredTiger uses document-level concurrency control for write operations. As a result, multiple clients can modify different documents of a collection at the same time.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#document-level-concurrency

Comment: There are brief answers to the locking and concurrency related topics in the [MongoDB v4.4 Manual's FAQ: Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/): What type of locking does MongoDB use? How granular are the locks? How do I see the status of locks on mongod instances? Does a read or write operation ever yield the lock? What locks are taken by some common client operations? Which admin commands lock a database or collection? Does a MongoDB operation ever lock more than one database? How do sharding and replica-set affect concurrency? Does MongoDB support transactions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is not per connection, it is per `mongod`. In other words the lock will exist across all connections to the `test` database on that server.

It is also a read/write lock so if a write is occuring then a read must wait, otherwise how can MongoDB know it is a consistent read?

However I should mention that MongoDB locks are very different to SQL/normal transactional locks you get and normally a lock will be held for about a microsecond between average updates.

Comment: The second statement helps a lot - I couldn't find anywhere that they were queued, so I was worried that it was just grabbing data that may not be consistent.

Also I was aware of the slight delay, it's fine in my particular situation. Thanks!

Comment: `normally a lock will be held for about a microsecond` if you held a lock for one microsecond then by the laws of physics you can't **guarantee write durability**.

Comment: @PabloFernandez reference? You can ensure write durability on micro locks it just depends on the type of lock you possess, as William's answer explains in more detail

Comment: as of 2015 there's no durable device with 1µs latency, if you're releasing the lock in less than that the value is not persisted.

Comment: I'll elaborate: the best SSD drives can perform 1M IOPS (that's not even close to the median: AWS EBS, for example defaults to 30k IOPS), by that definition the disk write alone takes 1µs. If your whole stack (JVM, OS, SSD) takes 1µs, then you're most definitely caching somewhere and not persisting to disk.

Comment: This is more evident with William's answer, claiming that mongo executes 2M writes/s, when the fastest SSD drive know to date can only do 1.2M IOPS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS#Solid-state_devices).

Comment: @PabloFernandez would need more investigation as to how MongoDB actually writes to open files in it's c++ code however, I see no reason why William would have lied in his answer, best thing to do is ask 10gen about it

Comment: The answer is easy to find (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/fsync/) mongodb persists data in disk once every 60 seconds, so if you have, like William said, 2M writes per second you can **loose up to 120.000.000 documents** in an ordinary machine reboot.

Comment: @PabloFernandez a write to the fsync queue could be what William is referring to, I am unsure

Comment: @PabloFernandez but since that writes to RAM it should be able to do a lot more than that

Comment: I do not know what a "fsync queue" is, perhaps a mongodb (in memory) internal structure? anyway and returning to my original idea: if your write operation takes 1µs (or even 0.5µs like William says) to complete then **you can't guarantee** that the data reached a durable device.

Comment: @PabloFernandez meh, people make mistakes

Answer (score 265):

### MongoDB Locking is Different

Locking in MongoDB does not work like locking in an RDBMS, so a bit of explanation is in order.  In earlier versions of MongoDB, there was a single global reader/writer latch.  Starting with MongoDB 2.2, there is a reader/writer latch for each database.

### The readers-writer latch

The latch is multiple-reader, single-writer, and is writer-greedy.  This means that:

- There can be an unlimited number of simultaneous readers on a database
- There can only be one writer at a time on any collection in any one database (more on this in a bit)
- Writers block out readers
- By "writer-greedy", I mean that once a write request comes in, all readers are blocked until the write completes (more on this later)

Note that I call this a "latch" rather than a "lock".  This is because it's lightweight, and in a properly designed schema the write lock is held on the order of a dozen or so microseconds.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) for more on readers-writer locking.

In MongoDB you can run as many simultaneous queries as you like: as long as the relevant data is in RAM they will all be satisfied without locking conflicts.

### Atomic Document Updates

Recall that in MongoDB the level of transaction is a single document.  All updates to a single document are Atomic.  MongoDB achieves this by holding the write latch for only as long as it takes to update a single document in RAM.  If there is any slow-running operation (in particular, if a document or an index entry needs to be paged in from disk), then that operation will *yield* the write latch.  When the operation yields the latch, then the next queued operation can proceed.

This does mean that the writes to all documents within a single database get serialized.  This can be a problem if you have a poor schema design, and your writes take a long time, but in a properly-designed schema, locking isn't a problem.

### Writer-Greedy

A few more words on being writer-greedy:

Only one writer can hold the latch at one time; multiple readers can hold the latch at a time.  In a naive implementation, writers could starve indefinitely if there was a single reader in operation.  To avoid this, in the MongoDB implementation, once any single thread makes a write request for a particular latch

- All subsequent readers needing that latch will block
- That writer will wait until all current readers are finished
- The writer will acquire the write latch, do its work, and then release the write latch
- All the queued readers will now proceed

The actual behavior is complex, since this writer-greedy behavior interacts with yielding in ways that can be non-obvious.  Recall that, starting with release 2.2, there is a *separate* latch for each database, so writes to any collection in database 'A' will acquire a separate latch than writes to any collection in database 'B'.

### Specific questions

Regarding the specific questions:

- Locks (actually latches) are held by the MongoDB kernel for only as long as it takes to update a single document
- If you have multiple connections coming in to MongoDB, and each one of them is performing a series of writes, the latch will be held on a per-database basis for only as long as it takes for that write to complete
- Multiple connections coming in performing writes (update/insert/delete) will all be interleaved

While this sounds like it would be a big performance concern, in practice it doesn't slow things down.  With a properly designed schema and a typical workload, MongoDB will saturate the disk I/O capacity -- even for an SSD -- before lock percentage on any database goes above 50%.

The highest capacity MongoDB cluster that I am aware of is currently performing 2 million writes per second.

Comment: I understood the logic behind writer-greedy "locking" - just not at which point it would lock others out. This helped. Thanks!

Comment: I need some precisions about the "writer-greedy" concept :

When you say "once a write request comes in, all readers are blocked until the write completes (more on this later)" the write request block all readers on the entire database or just the collection (or document)?

Does a reader operation block a write operation?

Thank you

Comment: @FredMériot currently it will block it on database level but document level locking is already in the dev branch. Yes a reader operation can block a write, MongoDB cannot read consistently is something is being written to

Comment: Even death doesn't stop this guy from helping people! RIP William

Comment: For those wondering what happened to William, take a read here: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/99566492653/announcing-the-william-zola-outstanding. RIP

Comment: This comment has helped me a great deal to understand locking in details, more than anything I've found so far. RIP.

Comment: Collection level locking is available since 2.7.8. Take a look: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240

Comment: if multiple reads are possible at the signal point there is a problem of dirty ready how we overcome this.

Answer (score 23):

Mongo 3.0 now supports collection-level locking.

In addition to this, now Mongo created an API that allows to create a storage engine. Mongo 3.0 comes with 2 storage engines:

1. **MMAPv1**: the default storage engine and the one use in the previous versions. Comes with collection-level locking.
2. **WiredTiger**: the new storage engine, comes with document-level locking and compression. (Only available for the 64-bit version)

[MongoDB 3.0 release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0/)

[WiredTiger](http://www.wiredtiger.com/)

Answer (score 10):

I know the question is pretty old but still some people are confused....

> Starting in MongoDB 3.0, the WiredTiger storage engine (which uses **document-level concurrency**) is available in the 64-bit builds.
>
> WiredTiger uses document-level concurrency control for write operations. As a result, multiple clients can modify different documents of a collection at the same time.
>
> For most read and write operations, WiredTiger uses optimistic concurrency control. WiredTiger uses only intent locks at the global, database and collection levels. When the storage engine detects conflicts between two operations, one will incur a write conflict causing MongoDB to transparently retry that operation.
>
> Some global operations, typically short lived operations involving multiple databases, still require a global “instance-wide” lock. Some other operations, such as dropping a collection, still require an exclusive database lock.

[Document Level Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#document-level-concurrency/)

Comment: Maybe people are confused because the mongo documentation is not clear what is meant by "optimistic concurrency control".  Regurgitating the docs does not really help.