# Load balancing cloudformation mongodb from elastic beanstalk requests

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk autoscaling architecture that queries a 3 node mongodb cloudformation stack.

```
Elastic Beanstalk |
     server1
     server2 (autoscaled clone of server1)    
     server3 (autoscaled clone of server1)    

mongodb CloudFormation |    
     replicanode0    
     replicanode1    
     replicanode2
```

Each ec2 box in the mongo stack has a different IP address. When I deploy the node app on the elastic beanstalk I give it the IP address of replicaNode0.

But how do they access the other nodes? Do I have to create a load balancer between the server stack and the DB stack? Or does Mongo just do this magically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB load balancing in multiple AWS instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671205/mongodb-load-balancing-in-multiple-aws-instances)