# Prevent duplicated document insertion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, duplicates

I'm building a web hook that will receive POST requests from Facebook. In each request, there's a `facebookId` field that will be used to insert a new record in database. `facebookId` should be unique in the database (meaning **no two records should have the same** `facebookId`). 
The prototype code is something like this

```
postRequestHandler(req) {
  const facebookId = req.body.facebookId;
  if (!Meteor.users.findOne({ facebookId })) {
    Meteor.users.insert({ 
      facebookId,
      // some other fields
    })
  }    
}
```

The problem is, sometimes when there are many requests (yes, they have different meaning) containing the **same new** `facebookId` (which is not existed in the database) and **they come almost at the same time**. This will make the `!Meteor.users.findOne({ facebookId })` check failed, and multiple records with same `facebookId` field will be inserted to the database. How do I prevent this ?

Comment: I think this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456671/to-what-level-does-mongodb-lock-on-writes-or-what-does-it-mean-by-per-connec

Answer (score 2):

You should create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on your `facebookId` field to have MongoDB guarantee uniqueness across your data and then add some exception handling code around your the callback that your `insert` call returns (documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-insert)). You will need to judge based on your business requirements what the right exception handling code should look like.

```
Meteor.users.insert({ 
    facebookId,
    // some other fields
}, function(error, id) { 
    if ( error ) {
        /* add exception handling code here, e.g. return an error message to the client */
    } else {
        /* add code for successful case here, 'id' will be your newly inserted document's '_id' */
    }
});
```