# How can I ensure only one document with X value exists in Mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have multiple software instances writing/reading from the same Mongodb instance, and I need to ensure that a document with value X of field Y have been inserted only once within T period.

I am stuck on figuring out how to achieve that, I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456671/to-what-level-does-mongodb-lock-on-writes-or-what-does-it-mean-by-per-connec) and I understand that Mongodb locks db until current write finishes, however this will not be enough to guarantee the target.

A scenario I am expecting to happen is demonstrated in the following:

[image: Diagram]

And the result will be a duplicated document.

I am thinking that one solution might be to lock db from "read from Mongodb" till "write to Mongodb" steps, but I am not sure if that is possible to do with Mongodb.

**Update:**

it is okay to have a duplicated document if period T has passed since first document with value X of field Y is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding unique index on field Y - in your case 2nd instance should get an error when creating document because document of value X for field Y already exists.

to make an index: ([more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/))

```
db.yourCollection.createIndex( { "Y": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

// remarks after question update

in that case solution I provided will not be sufficient. 
probably what will work is adding field which keeps timestamp of last update (lets call it `updated_at`) and later on running upsert command taking into consideration `updated_at` and `Y`

```
db.yourCollection.update(
  {
    updated_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2018-06-01T01:00:00.000Z") # one hour interval
    },
    Y: {
      $exists: false
    }
  },
  {
    upsert: true
  }
)
```

please note that collection will require index on both `updated_at` and `Y` to be performant as collection grows

Comment: thank you, question is updated, do you think index will still work?

Comment: Still figuring out, in my case if the record is duplicate I want to just through exception instead of updating the old one

Comment: document will be create only once - it's how `upsert` works (check: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)